# Can't use pytesseract in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, ocr

I tried to use pytesseract:

```
    import pytesseract
    from PIL import Image
    pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Python27\\scripts\\pytesseract.exe'
    im = Image.open('Download.png')
    print pytesseract.image_to_string(im)
```

But I got this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Python27/ocr.py", line 11, in <module>
        print pytesseract.image_to_string(im)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 
             125, in image_to_string
  raise TesseractError(status, errors)
  TesseractError: (2, u'Usage: python pytesseract.py [-l lang] input_file')
```

What is wrong?

Comment: i would be more then happy to help you out but it would require more information. please let me know what you are trying to do exactly with this code

Comment: Read text from an image.

Comment: there is a function called `run_tesseract` in "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", you could print `command` there to instigate further.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install tesseract using windows installer available [here](https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki). Then you should install the python wrapper as:

```
pip install pytesseract
```

Then you should also set the tesseract path in your script after importing pytesseract library as below (Please do not forget that installation path might be modified in your case!):

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
```

Note: It is tested on Anaconda3, Anaconda2, Py3 and Py2 without any issues.

Answer (score -1):

I think there is something wrong with your path 'C:\Python27\scripts\pytesseract.exe', This seems to point to the pytessaract.py code (hence the error has pytessaract.py on it - the exact error is mentioned in the main function of pytessaract.py which runs only if **name** == "**main**" ).

The path must actually point to tessaract.exe, downloaded separately. Look at the 3rd point under installation in the link (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytesseract).

This has to be done because pytesseract is only a python wrapper around the tessaract program, so it calls tessaract.exe on your local machine for doing the actual ocr work.